# Using PHP's exec() gives error: Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install

Tags: php, ubuntu, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to use PHP to `exec()` a binary `casperjs`,

```
exec('casperjs /var/www/mysite/application/phantomjs/test.js');
```

but I am getting the error

```
Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?
```

CasperJS runs on top of PhantomJS, both which I manually installed and created a link at `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs` and `/usr/local/bin/casperjs`. So I am guessing casperjs calls phantomjs when it runs.

However it works fine when I ssh into the server and run

```
casperjs /var/www/mysite/application/phantomjs/test.js
```

What went wrong? I think `casperjs` cannot run `phantomjs` as a web user? If this is true, how can it be fixed?

Comment: try `exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs /var/www/mysite/application/phantomjs/test.js');`

Comment: @Ascherer I'm getting the same error. `Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to call the `exec` command with the full path of the program. For example

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs /var/www/mysite/application/phantomjs/test.js');
```

Also make sure that you are allowed to execute that program via the web server, especially if you use the php `safe_mode on`. Have a look at [safe_mode_exec_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir)

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.4.9, so theres no `safe_mode` line in my `php.ini`. Using the full path of the program gives me the same error, maybe `casperjs` is not calling `phantomjs` using its full path.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem and found a working solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/casperjs/92yUM9O0XjA

Comment: On OSX if you don't install phantomjs via homebrew and use the executable pre-compiled on their website then you need to specify the actual location of phantomjs via an env variable: `export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/phantomjs`

Comment: I had the same problem on Centos 6.9 and this answer also worked (add these lines to your PHP script above the exec: putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");)