# How to open a CasperJS/PhantomJS file in a browser like Google Chrome?

Tags: browser, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I'm new on using a headless browser (CasperJS/PhantomJS), and I'm using it for web scraping so I can scrape AJAX sites.

But I have a question about it:

**I need to open the file in a common browser like Google Chrome, so does anyone know if there is a way to do that?**

I already have this code in a file "test.js":

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
this.echo("a" + this.getTitle());
});
```

If I run this file by using the the command line (CMD), it works:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC1im.png]

But I also tried to change it into a HTML file so it can be opened by a web browser:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var casper = require('casper').create();
        casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
        });

        casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
        this.echo("a" + this.getTitle());
        });

        casper.run();
    </script>
</body>
```

When I open this HTML file in Google Chrome, I get this error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o56U9.png]

Any ideas?

Edit: I am finally able to run CasperJS on a browser by using PHP. Here's the PHP code if anyone needs it in the future, I hope it will help you:

```
<?php
    $text = exec("casperjs C:/Users/User/Desktop/CasperFile.js");
    echo $text;
?>
```

Font: [Cannot pass CasperJS result back to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001258/cannot-pass-casperjs-result-back-to-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run CasperJS directly from a browser like Google Chrome or Firefox.

If this was possible, it would allow for violations of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

To get around any restrictions, you should do your web scraping server-side.

Since, according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303489/how-to-open-a-casperjs-phantomjs-file-in-a-browser-like-google-chrome#comment89584441_51303712), you are using PHP, you can use a PHP wrapper for CasperJS:

- [php-casperjs](https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs)
- [casperjs-php](https://github.com/synackSA/casperjs-php) (an extension of the above library)

Alternatively, you can use the `exec` command:

```
$result = exec('PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs script.js');
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you @Grant Miller! This sounds much better because I wasn't going to run it on command line every time I need to scrape the data. So, I've already installed "php-casperj" and I pasted the code from the example, but when I try to run it, I get this message: "Fatal error: Class 'Browser\Casper' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\web scraping\web scraping.php on line 3", do you know how to fix it?

Comment: By the way, I also tried the exec command in a PHP file, but when I open it in Chrome, I don't see anything (it's not printing the result). I changed the path of the "PhantomJS_Executable" because mine is located in C:\PhantomJs\bin: https://i.imgur.com/UVwvAxa.png, so I wrote this: https://i.imgur.com/7cT2us6.png and finally, test1.js has this: https://i.imgur.com/GS1zGtH.png (it's an example I got from the phatom official site). So, what's wrong?

Comment: I am finally able to run CasperJS on PHP! Your exec code didn't work for me @Grant Miller, maybe because I am using Windows instead of Linux? Anyways, I've just found another code to do it so I'll edit my first post and I will put it there for the people who will have the same question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it won't work. What you're trying to do is akin to opening an MS Word file with a videoplayer.

A script is not an HTML page, it's a program and Google Chrome is not CasperJS/PhantomJS and therefore won't run scripts designed for them.

If you want to do scraping in a browser your best bet is creating [a browser extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

Comment: Thank you! But sadly, I can't use a browser extension because I have to build a website by using HTML/JavaScript or PHP and I need to get the data from some websites by using a programming language.

Comment: Well, both PHP and PhantomJS work on the server so you could still do that. But why not start with some Scraping 101 book or article?

Comment: Well, I have to scrape some hotel websites to get their prices, not a book or article. I already tried to scrape them by using "Simple HTML DOM" for PHP and it seemed to work fine to get some data, but it doesn't work if I need to get a data which it isn't in the main HTML (because those sites tend to make AJAX calls). So, that's why I am trying to use a headless browser, to scrape dynamic sites succesfully. And yes, PHP and PhantomJS work on the server, but Phantom is based on JavaScript so probably it won't be compatible with PHP.